# Как сделать так чтобы во время отчёта нельзя было использовать класс Scanner?

Tags: java

Во время отчёта я могу использовать Scanner как сделать так, чтобы запретить это делать? `sec.setTimer(10);
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`

А вот и сам метод:

```
public void setTimer(int sec){
    System.out.print("Вы сможете писать через: ");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int radix = sec;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(radix==0){
                timer.cancel();
                System.out.println("Вы можете писать!"); return;
            }
            System.out.println(radix); radix--;

        }
    }, sec*200, sec*100);
}
```